# UITableView titleForHeaderInSection does not returns correct stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I encounter a strange problem when attempting to return a composite string in the tableView's titleForHeaderIn section.

If I NSLog the string, it seems to be good, but when i return it, it crashes !

Here's my code :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"favorites",@"");
NSLog(@"%@", title); // this prints the correct title ("Items" for example...)

int number = (*_tabsections_especes)[0][0];
NSLog(@"%d", number); // this prints the correct number ( "5", for example...)

NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %d", title, number ] );
    // this prints the correct concatenated string ("Items : 5", for example);

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %d)", title, number ];
    // --> this either crashes the app, or returns anything in the title, 
    // for example the title of a resource image or another pointer...
    }
```

If I replace "(*_tabsections_especes)[0][0]" by "5", for example, the problem persists.
So, it seems that the issue is about using NSLocalizedString in the stringWithFormat method, then returning it.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sounds to me like your return value is being released before the Table View can access it. Have you tried setting title directly, without NSLocalizedString?

Comment: Yes, actually it's worse ! if I write only : `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)", @"titre", 5 ];`, the app crashes. I really do not understand what is going on ? This piece of code is still very simple ?

Comment: It must be something else. I am working on an app with Table Views myself and substituted your code for my own and it worked fine. I also commented out all my other datasource and delegate methods, the methods setting the delegate and the delegate ivar and it still drew the table with your header. Baffling! Can you upload the complete code for your UITableViewController subclass somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you're right, Keith ! I have found an ivar which is not retain in a custom subclass of UIView, that i use in place of (UIView)viewForHeaderInSection. The crash comes from this class, and not from titleForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Glad to help. I know how tough it is struggling to track down bugs. If I put this in an answer, can you accept it and boost my rep. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem was.
Actually it was not in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection`, but rather in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`.

In fact, it is because I use a subclass of UIView for the viewForHeaderInSection.
In this subclass, I have an ivar named "title".

In the init method of this subclass, I set this ivar like this :

```
title = myTitle;  // (myTitle is an argument of the custom init method)
```

And, just later, I use this title like this in the drawRect method :

```
[title drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(8, 9) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19]];
```

This works fine if I pass a static string like @"example string" from titleForHeaderInSection, and via viewForHEaderInSection.

But not at all if I pass an autorelease object like stringWithFormat.

So, the solution is simply to retain my ivar in the subclass like this:

```
title = [myTitle retain];
```

and to release it in the dealloc method of my subclass:

```
[title dealloc];
```

Like this, it works and it doesn't crash. I hope this helps and that the explanations are clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use this before

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %d)", title, number ];
return result;
```

or use this

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initStringWithFormat:@"%@ : %d)", title, number ]]autorelease];
return result;
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as what OP is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your method and it works. Look for your bug elsewhere.